# Enter 2 by n matrix (permutation notation) as inline math without taking up much space

Tags: spacing, arrays, inline

I need to use something that looks like a 2 by n matrix as inline math.  How can I achieve this without it pushing the lines apart?

Example:

```
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & \dots & N \\
i_1 & i_2 & \dots & i_N
\end{array}\right)
```

[image]

The problem with this code is that it takes as much space as display math would even when used as inline math.  I would like it to take no more space than a `\frac{...}{...}` or `\binom{...}{...}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `smallmatrix` environment from the amsmath package will do this.  It will not take up much space when used inline.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
This is a permutation, represented as a $2\times n$ matrix and squeezed into a single line:
$\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & 2 & \cdots & n\\
i_1 & i_2 & \cdots & i_n
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.
Use the smallmatrix environment to typeset it.  It will not push lines apart like the array environment would.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have found the answer.  Please let me know if this question should be deleted.

Comment: I would recommend you leave the question. You are probably not the last person who will have this issue, so this can help others. However, I would recommend you post a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, just wanted to prevent any bad reactions, but TeX.SE is quite a bit friendlier than many other SE sites :-)

Comment: with `mathtools` package you can also have `smallpmatrix` etc.

Comment: @percusse I made the answer community wiki, so please feel free to add this information (or your own separate answer if you wish).

Comment: @Szabolcs Where is the fun in that? :P You should keep CW to reaaaaaaaally community wikis. This is not SO and we don't care about rep :)

Comment: @percusse: we care about ducks. `:)`